# Java Scanner making a triangle with star( divided in four static void

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have to make something like this.

```
         *  
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
```

But my teacher required in some weird format have to follow. And using For loop statement. And the code i need to type is under (//Answer Here using For...loop)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IsoTri3
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        // declare viriable
        int height;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Input height
        System.out.print("Enter the height of triangle: ");
        height = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(height);                 
        // Print triangle
        // Print Top
        topRow ( height );
        // Print Middle
        for (int j=2; j<= height-1; j++)
        {
            innerRow(j, height);
        }
        // Print Bottom
        lastRow( height );
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    public static void topRow(int row)
    {
        //Answer Here using For...loop
    }

    public static void innerRow(int row,int h)
    {
        //Answer Here using For...loop
    }

    public static void lastRow(int h)
    {
        //Answer Here using For...loop
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: *Some weird format* is how you well-organized code is written. Breaking the problem into smaller steps 1) teaches you about methods 2) makes you think about the steps to the overall solution

Comment: I can do the program without devide in four static void. But when it devide, it fail printing * . So weird to do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a pattern here. Let's say the height is `n=5`. All rows have odd number `(2*n - 1)` of stars. Starting from first row, it goes like this: **1 star**, **3 stars**, **5 stars**, **7 stars** and **9 stars**. You see the pattern yet? On every row you have to print **2 more stars** than the previous row. Forget the formatting. First, print the stars following this pattern here.

Next comes the formatting. I am assuming that the last row has zero spaces in front of it. Now see the pattern here. On the 1st row you have to print `5-1=4` spaces, 2nd row you have `5-2=3` spaces, 3rd row you have `5-3=2` spaces, 4th row you have `5-4=1` space, and the 5th(last) row has `5-5=0` space.

Coding this will not be very tricky.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it again